# UIProgressView gets to value 100 before the actual float being 100

Tags: ios, objective-c

When using progressView inside a UITableViewCell, i use as so

```
       cell.imageView.file = (PFFile *)object[@"image"];
        [cell.imageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage * _Nullable image, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        } progressBlock:^(int percentDone) {
            NSLog(@"%d",percentDone);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [cell.progressBar setProgress:percentDone animated:YES];
            });
            if (percentDone == 100) {
                [cell.progressBar setHidden:YES];
            }

        }];
```

Im NSLogging the percentDone, and the progressView gets to 100 before the percentDone gets to 100. This is on the second cell so maybe something to do with reuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The progress in `UIProgressView` is represented as a value between `0.00` and `1.00`. If your values are integers `0` through `100`, you want to multiply them by `0.01`.

```
[cell.progressBar setProgress:percentDone * 0.01 animated:YES];
```